# Javascript text change is not fixing inside HTML "for"

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have this course project where I have a list of posts, for the user that posted is shown a button or link to edit the post. I need to replace the old post for a textarea with the old text, edit the text, save and show the new post.
The big problem is when i click the edit button I see the text change to the textarea, but it doesn´t stay (one or two seconds), it desapears before i can change the post content. The old post shows like nothing happend. Is there someone that can give me a tip on this?

**Javascript**

```
function editpost(postid, page){
   alert("edit link clicked");
   const oldtext = document.getElementById(`${postid}`).innerHTML;
   const newtext = document.getElementById(`${postid}`);

   newtext.innerHTML = `
     <textarea id=${postid} > ${oldtext} </textarea>
     <button id="change-${postid}" class="btn btn-success" onclick="changepost(${postid}, ${page})" 
             type="submit" style="width:30%;">Change</button>
     <button id="cancel-${postid}" class="btn btn-danger"  onclick="cancel()" 
             type="cancel"style="width:30%;">Cancel</button>
   `;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   {%for Post in page_obj %}
        <div class="container" >
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <p> {{ Post.User |title }} </p>
                
                    {% if UserEdit|title == Post.User|title %}
                         <p>
                         <a href="" id="edit-{{Post.id}}" onclick="editpost({{Post.id}},'profile')"> 
                             Edit Post
                         </a></p>
                    {% endif %}
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-8" style="text-align: center;">

                        <div id="post-{{Post.id}}"  >
                            <p id={{Post.id}}> {{Post.Post}} </p>
                        </div>

                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
   
    {% endfor %}
```

Thank you all in advanced for the help.

Comment: A button in a form with no `type` defaults to `type="submit"` . You are not preventing the default form submit so the page reloads. Try adding `type="button"`  to buttons not used to submit. Also do some research on preventing default form submit and preventing default event actions

Comment: thanks , your comment with the answer combined workded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace anchor tag with button tag like that

```
{% if UserEdit|title == Post.User|title %}
<p>
<button id="edit-{{Post.id}}" onclick="editpost({{Post.id}},'profile')">
Edit Post</button>
</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: And why does that help?

Comment: Thanks! your answer and the comment combined worked!